# Tell linker to ignore __declspec(dllexport) in 3rd-party static library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When I build `opus` static library, its functions are marked for dllexport. If then I use this lib in my own dll, it exports opus functions as well. Is there any way to tell linker to ignore them without rebuilding the lib?

Comment: Looking at opus_defines.h looks like defining OPUS_EXPORT as empty macro before including any opus headers might get rid of dllexport (because it is surrounded with ifndef).

Comment: I already did that, thanks.